# How to read csv files from folder , Read first 10 files and save in one csv , read next 10 files and save in other csv file and so on

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
path = r'D:/PYTHON/My codes/Frequency envelopes/test'

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

names = [os.path.basename(x) for x in all_files]

df = pd.DataFrame()

for file_, name in zip(all_files, names):

    file_df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=False)

    file_df['file_name'] = name
    df = df.append(file_df)
```

**This piece of code is working for read all files from directory and save in one file, i want to read first 10 files from directory and save in one csv file and next 10 files from same directory to save in other csv and so on i want to do this until not complete all csv files in directory , if anyone have solution please mention here  **

Comment: Correct me if I am misunderstanding something. But couldn't you just warp the two last lines of code in a for loop that counts from 0 to 10 and writes a file. Then once the loop breaks, change the filename and start over (you can use a while loop for the outer one). That is the high level idea. Let me know if you require further guidance.

Comment: Please can you add piece of code for this ? and also is that possible to clear memory after finish every loop ? Because i am facing trouble . i am using 106GB data , when i run my code its occupy 60GB RAM and run code for one whole day and one night but still running .

Comment: I didn't give you an answer because I don't think I have a good solution for it. With large data-sets you should think ways to simplify the space complexity and the execution time. However, let me tell you something about StackOverflow. Try to give all your problems and what you want to solve i the question. Adding follow-up questions is a very bad practice. -> https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem

Answer (score 0):

Add nrows=10 to read first 10 lines.

```
import pandas

for file_, name in zip(all_files, names):

    file_df = pd.read_csv(file_,nrows=10)    #reading first ten lines

    file_df['file_name'] = name
    df = df.append(file_df)
```

Comment: I don't want to read rows of csv , I have 100 csv files in one folder i want to save first 10 csv files in one csv and next 10 files in other csv file and so on .....

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, split your list into `list` of `list` , each sublist contain 10 items

```
names=[names[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(names), 3)]

all_files=[all_files[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(all_files), 3)]


for file, name in zip(all_files, names):
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    for x , y in zip(file,name):
        file_df = pd.read_csv(x,index_col=False)

        file_df['file_name'] = y
        df = df.append(file_df)
        df.to_csv(name+'.csv')
```

Comment: your logic is work working but saving in csv file line have some problem